# Qt - Specify custom build settings in project file [.pro]

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, properties, custom-build-step

Without Qt Creator...

Do you know how to specify Custom Build Settings specific to a header file in the project file for a C++/Qt solution ? I would like specifically to set the Command Line and Outputs settings from these property sheet below (in VS 2013, right click on header file) into the project file.

[image]

How is the syntax ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: In other words you'd like to pass extra flags only when compiling a specific cpp?